# Is there a way to individually modify n objects with the same origin object in game engine?

Tags: mesh, game-engine

**The problem:**

I created a number of mesh objects with the Edit Object -> Add object actuator in the Blender game scene. I then modify the vertices in one of them, trying to change the vertices of only that mesh object. All of the copies of the object are modified as a result instead.

**The question:**

How can I make the mesh objects individually modifiable?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that each of these objects still has the same mesh, so modifying the mesh of one object appears to modify all the meshes. Two possible solutions are: make separate meshes for each object, difficult to do in the game engine; make all the objects in blender, then load them in the game engine.
I'd suggest finding a new way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.  If this hasn't changed your mind, these two threads give some hints at what I think you're trying to do.
[moving and creating objects in the game engine](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-296586.html)
[creating a new mesh in the game engine](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?40026-create-a-new-mesh-in-game-engine)

Comment: This answer is insufficient and the .blend links are out of order. Having an arbitrary amount of different meshes available in the game engine is required in what I am trying to create. If the answer must extend to the realm of altering the source code of the game engine, so be it. I will be waiting for another answer. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Without knowing details then, I'd suggest using a python script to create the objects before running the game engine.

Comment: The idea is to create new mesh objects during the game engine runtime. The amount of objects produced will depend on the player's actions, so the objects cannot be pre-created before the game engine initializes.